# Angular 14 / windows : error while creating new project

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

Environment :

- windows 10.0.19043 Build 19043
- Node v14.20.0
- npm 6.14.17
- Angular 14.0.6

While creating a new projet with angular 14

```
ng new my-project
```

I face that error:

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

there's a lot threads over internet about that issue. Some state to try clearing the npm cache and then launch again the packages installation

```
npm cache clear --force
npm i
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the problem by installing the latest 16.16.0 nodejs version  at the time of writing along with the latest npm ones 8.14.0 as nodejs does not do the job.

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```